# Failed to load image SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have an issue with my SFML on windows. I'm usually used to work under Linux but this time I'm on VSCode on windows. So I'm trying to load an image from my file called `toto.png`. But when I draw it, I have an error `Failed to load image` which appears every time. I first thought that is was my function, so I tried to draw the sprite directly in my main function but same error, then I thought it was coming from my path, so I copied past the image in all the possible folder of the project, but event with that, it still doesn't work.

```cpp
#include "Window.hpp"
#include "Grid.hpp"


WindowHandling::WindowHandling()
{
    _window.create(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "2048");
}

void WindowHandling::DrawWindow()
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    texture.loadFromFile("toto.png");
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    std::unique_ptr<Grid> Map(new Grid());
    while (_window.isOpen()) {
        Map->CreateGrid(_window);
        while (_window.pollEvent(_event)) {
            if (_event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                _window.close();
            _window.draw(sprite);
        }
        //_window.clear(sf::Color(220, 220, 220));
        _window.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify working directory in your VSCode project run settings to the path with image.

```
.vscode/launch.json
```

Add line:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

To the "Configurations" section

Or run it directly via .exe from directory you have compiled into

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, I was executing the project in `debug` instead of `release`...